# Averaging time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula in Excel that will average negative times with positive times, I have a spread sheet calculating early, on time and late arrivals, and I would like to calculate the average over a certain time frame. I have tried several, but they just average the positive times. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what format are these times? If it's just minutes, say +30 minutes here and -10 minutes there, you can just use =AVERAGE().

Comment: I am actually trying to calculate an average on the calculated difference, for example 3:00 a.m on time goal, actual delivery time could be 2:30 am, giving me negative time or delivery time could be later than the goal time

Answer (score 0):

First set up the 1904 date system, then with data in column **D**, use something like:

```
=AVERAGE(D1:D17)
```

[image]